# Debian Sqeeze Issue - GPU Hangs

Tags: graphics, hardware, debian, driver, linux-device-driver

This happened after I performed a clean install of Debian Squeeze 6.0.5 on my Zenith PC with Intel Graphics card. The installation went smooth and the Gnome desktop is very fast and responsive. However, every now and then the desktop just freezes at certain events. This happened on a few occasions:

1. When I opened an html file in the epiphany browser.
2. A user logged out.
3. A flash-drive was inserted.

When the desktop froze, I switched to a tty terminal by pressing alt+f1 and performed a root login. When I then tried to switch to my main desktop, I read this on the black screen:

```
X.Org X Server 1.7.7
Release Date: 2010-05-04
X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
Build Operating System: Linux 2.6.32-5-amd64 i686 Debian
Current Operating System: Linux workstation1 2.6.32-5-686 #1 SMP Sun May 6 04:01:19........
Kernel Command Line....
...
...
..
FATAL: Module fbcon not found.
SELinux: Disabled on system, not enabling in X server
(EE) Intel(0): Detected a hung GPU, disabling acceleration.
```

To me this seems to be a driver related issue, though it could also be an X related problem. My graphics card is of type:

```
Intel(R) 82845G/GL/GE/PE/GV Graphics Controller
```

Is there a way to know whether Debian has installed the correct driver? I do have all the driver CDs that came with my PC, but they are specifically for the Windows OS.

Could any of you Debian Experts throw some light on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other people seems to have been having problems with that chipset as well:
http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=71083

You could give the vesa driver a spin and see if that works:
http://packages.debian.org/sid/xserver-xorg-video-vesa

Remember to remove other drivers. 
I'm not a Debian user but you should be able to list installed packages with:

```
dpkg -l
```

If the list is to long just grep for xserver or xorg.

Comment: When I perform "dpkg -l", I get a list of several xserver.org driver packages including Intel, VESA, VMWare, Voodoo, Strident, etc. Any idea how to find out what driver X is currently using, and how to switch configuration to use the VESA driver?

Comment: You should probably take a look at this page: http://wiki.debian.org/Xorg/ Driver in use should be mentioned in your xorg.conf file, look for Driver

Comment: You could also try "sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg" to reconfigure your settings

Answer (score 0):

I ran the command: `Xorg -configure`. After doing some R&D, this is what worked for me after editing the xorg.conf:

```
Option "DRI" "false"
Option "Tiling" "false"
Option "Shadow" "true"
```

Now my desktop runs rock-solid without getting hung. To verify, I deliberately tried to bring the system down by opening several instances of browsers, terminals, synaptic (and even eclipse!), this setting didn't fail. And of course, removing these settings from xorg.conf again caused my desktop to freeze when I "stress-tested" it.

Comment: I've also tried replacing the vesa driver with the intel one after disabling kms. That method worked too! Here is a detailed post on how I went about doing that in case someone wants to do it: http://tuxwarrior10.wordpress.com/2012/07/15/intel-graphic-cards-issue/